# Is there any way I can shift the whole html canvas to the left or right making room for a sidebar menu on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I saw many apps that can do this: When you click a menu expand icon. The whole content moves to the right or left. making some room for the menu.

Is it possible to shift the whole existing page to the right or left out of the screen, making room for the menu? If so, how can I achieve it with CSS or JavaScript?

[image]

Comment: please provide some code. are you trying to make a menu like the one in https://www.tesla.com/modelx

Comment: Hi there it is possible, You can achieve this with 3 options that I am aware of.

Jquery, Javascript and CSS keyframes. However there are options available where you can get templet code of this

Comment: I am working on a piece of code for you :)

Comment: Not tesla, it's not shifting the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS Below

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.menu-switch').draggable({containment: "parent"});
      $('.menu-switch').click(function(){
        $('.content').toggleClass('show-menu');
      });
      $('.left-menu span').click(function(){
        $('.content').toggleClass('show-menu');
      });
    })
```

CSS Below

```
    .content {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s linear;
      transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s linear;
      transition: transform 0.3s linear;
      transition: transform 0.3s linear, -webkit-transform 0.3s linear;
    }
    .content.show-menu {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
              transform: translateX(200px);
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s linear;
      transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s linear;
      transition: transform 0.3s linear;
      transition: transform 0.3s linear, -webkit-transform 0.3s linear;
    }
    .content .inner-content {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width: 60%;
      padding: 20px 30px;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .content .menu-switch {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      left: 2%;
      top: 2%;
      padding: 10px 13px;
      background:#999;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .content .left-menu {
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      left: -200px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .content .left-menu span {
      position: absolute;
      left: 2%;
      top: 2%;
    }
    .content .left-menu .left-menu-content a {
      display: block;
    }
```

HTML Below

```
    <div class="content">
      <aside class="left-menu">
        <span class="fa fa-times-circle fa-lg fa-fw fa-inverse"></span>
        <div class="left-menu-header">
          <h3>My Menu<h3>
          <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="left-menu-content">
          <a href="#">Menut Item 1</a>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <nav class="menu-switch">
        <span class="fa fa-navicon fa-2x fa-inverse f-fw"></span>
      </nav>
      <div class="inner-content">
        <p>Page Content Would be over here</p>
      </div
    </div>
```

Comment: It's good. But it will have to put all the rest content in a "content" div.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem with an CSS animation that overlays the whole screen.
Have a look at the 9th example from Eduard L. in the link below you can pretty much do the same thing you only need to adjust the navbar how you like it and make the animation way bigger.

https://freefrontend.com/css-sidebar-menus/